# Magento : Get Invoice PDF Link on Frontend Customer Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, invoice, customer-account, pdf

I want to get download invoice PDF link in customer dashboard account, when they are inside their order.

Therefore I need to edit default code in file: `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/sales/order/info/buttons.phtml`

The default code is to download order PDF, but I want to change that to Invoice PDF.

Default code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getPrintUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-print" onclick="this.target='_blank';"></a>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Invoice link directly

Please check below example.

> Create one Front Controller

```
class [NameSpace]_[ModuleName]_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    protected function _initInvoice($update = false)
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Invoices'));
        $invoice = false;
        $itemsToInvoice = 0;
        $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        if ($invoiceId) {
            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId);
            if (!$invoice->getId()) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The invoice no longer exists.'));
                return false;
            }
        } elseif ($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            /**
             * Check order existing
             */
            if (!$order->getId()) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order no longer exists.'));
                return false;
            }
            /**
             * Check invoice create availability
             */
            if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order does not allow creating an invoice.'));
                return false;
            }
            $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys();
            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($savedQtys);
            if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            Mage::throwException($this->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
            }
        }

        Mage::register('current_invoice', $invoice);
        return $invoice;
    }

    protected function print()
    {
        if ($invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {
            if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)) {
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }

    public function printAction()
    {
        $this->_initInvoice();
        $this->print();
    }
}
```

> Edit items.phtml file and put below linke

Go to /app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/sales/order/invoice/items.phtml

```
<h2 class="sub-title">
<?php echo $this->__('Invoice #') ?><?php echo $_invoice->getIncrementId(); ?> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getPrintInvoiceUrl($_invoice) ?>" onclick="this.target='_blank'" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print Invoice') ?></a>
<!-- Add Invoice PDF Link  -->
<span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('[frontRouterName]/index/print',array('invoice_id'=>$_invoice->getId(),'order_id'=>$_order->getId())) ?>" onclick="this.target='_blank'" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print PDF') ?></a>
</h2>
```

You can directly download Invoice pdf

Comment: I used this , very nice. But "print()"  is reserved keyword in PHP so I had to rename to "printIt()"

Answer (score 0):

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\etc\modules\Maddy_Custompdf.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Custompdf>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
                 </Maddy_Custompdf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\local\Maddy\Custompdf\IndexController.php`

```
<?php

class Maddy_Custompdf_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        

    public function invoicesAction() {
        $orderId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

        if ($this->_canViewOrder($order)) {
            $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                    ->setOrderFilter($order->getId())
                    ->load();
            if ($invoices->getSize() > 0) {
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);

                return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                    'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
                    'application/pdf'
                );

            }
        }
    }

    protected function _canViewOrder($order)
    {
        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $availableStates = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates();
        if ($order->getId() && $order->getCustomerId() && ($order->getCustomerId() == $customerId)
            && in_array($order->getState(), $availableStates, $strict = true)
            ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\local\Maddy\Custompdf\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Custompdf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Maddy_Custompdf>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custompdf>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Maddy_Custompdf</module>
                    <frontName>custompdf</frontName>
                </args>
            </custompdf>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custombrand>
                    <file>custombrand.xml</file>
                </custombrand>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
  </config>
```

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\sales\order\history.php`

Add this line on line # 63 around below Reorder.

```
<strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('custompdf/index/invoices', array('order_id' => $_order->getId())) ?>">Print Invoices</a></strong>
```

It will surely Help.